# Form style layout - without s:Form

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I want a layout similar to the example image, but I don't want to use Spark Form. What's the best way to achieve this?

[image: form layout example]

- Each label is aligned right
- Each item is aligned left
- Label and item are centered horizontally.
- Item can be any item, not just text.

I don't want to use `FormLayout` because of difficulty styling the labels without creating a new skin for `Form`. Besides, it's not actually for a form anyway.

Comment: You could use [ConstraintLayout](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/layouts/ConstraintLayout.html). It's the base class for `FormLayout` and will do what you need, but it's also fairly complicated to use. Other than that you can write a custom layout. I have once written - without too much effort - a variant of TileLayout that could have variable column widths or variable row heights which could handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your only concern regarding form layout is skinning the form, note that you can achieve your desired result purely with style properties:

> [image: form]

Example form specifying `fx:Style`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

        s|FormItem s|Label#labelDisplay {
            textAlign: right;
            fontSize: 24px;
        }
        s|Label {
            fontSize: 24px;
        }
    </fx:Style>

    <s:Form>
        <s:layout>
            <s:FormLayout gap="-12" />
        </s:layout>

        <s:FormItem label="Label">
            <s:Label text="Item 1" />
        </s:FormItem>

        <s:FormItem label="Another Label">
            <s:Label text="Item 2" />
        </s:FormItem>

        <s:FormItem label="Even Longer Label">
            <s:Label text="Another Item" />
        </s:FormItem>
    </s:Form>

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this layout by using a **VBox** component:

```
<mx:VBox>
    <mx:Canvas>
        <mx:Label text="Label:Item 1"/>
    </mx:Canvas>    
    <mx:Canvas>
        <mx:Label text="Label:Item 2"/>
    </mx:Canvas>           
</mx:VBox>
```

A link to the API reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/VBox.html

Comment: If you enter the same label and item names, will the layout be the same as in my example? It looks like this won't work, the alignment would be off. Also this is flex 3 code, flex 4 uses `s:VGroup` instead of `mx:VBox`.